# Adjective for "being made mandatory"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, adjectives

I'm looking for a word like "mandatorised" (except it should be a real word) to describe something that's been transitioned from optional to mandatory.

Edit:

We're using this word to name a class in a piece of code we're writing, where the name needs to follow the pattern `<Adjective>Component`. E.g. we have `DeletedComponent` and `UpdatedComponent` to describe components that have had things "done" to them... we now need to capture the property of being transitioned from `optional` to `mandatory`, so `MandatorisedComponent` is the best we can currently come up with!

Comment: What's wrong with "mandated"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because [naming variables is off-topic] on this site.

Comment: Oops - [here’s the link](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Lawrence The question asks for a "real word", therefore it is on-topic. How they will use this word is up to them.

Comment: @michael.hor257k In that case, they should supply an English language context (sentence, paragraph, etc) for the word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, *mandatorized*, if it actually were a word, doesn't appear to be an adjective. In fact, *mandatory* is, itself, an adjective—but not what you're looking for.

Instead, *mandatorized* looks more like the past tense of a verb. It describes something that, to paraphrase you, "has had something done to it."

As such, an equivalent and existing word is **mandated**:

From one of Merriam-Webster's senses of the verb [*mandate*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mandate):

> **2** : to officially require (something) : make (something) mandatory : ORDER
>   // a law *mandating* recycling

Therefore, in your example, you would have a variable called `MandatedComponent`.

---

**Update**: I was just about to submit this as an answer when I noticed some other discussion in comments.

If you don't like the word *mandated*, because the past tense of the verb has the same spelling as the noun (and the noun could imply it has always been that way), then try something else:

`EnforcedComponent`

This, too, is the past tense of a verb but has a stronger implication of something having changed its state (from something unenforced), implying that something was done to it in the past.

For completeness, here is the Merriam-Webster definition of [*enforce*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/enforce):

> to carry out effectively
>   // the duty of the police is to enforce the law

Although this does not mean exactly the same thing, you generally *enforce* (verb) something that *is* mandatory (adjective). In the case of software, one would hope that if something has become mandatory it either has been or will be enforced.

`EnforcedComponent` also has the same parallel structure as `DeletedComponent` and `UpdatedComponent`.

Comment: @jsw29 If used as a *noun*, it could have always been something that is mandated. Such as a law. From the time it came into existed, it was a mandate (or a mandated policy). It existed in no other form. You are talking about the *verb*. I suggested the verb in my answer, but then read the comments where there was confusion between its noun and verb forms.

Comment: @jsw29 Statutory laws don't exist before they are enacted. By *law*, I'm talking about a legal document. As a *noun*, a mandate—unless revised afterwards—has always been as it was from the time of its creation. But I find this whole debate strange because it's only a side issue. The only reason I brought it up in my answer in the first place is because the person asking the original question commented that they didn't like the word *mandated* as the answer they were looking for. It originally *was* my answer—I just added to it in order to address their concern.

Answer (score 0):

I guess native speakers will understand "mandatorized", even if it is a new coinage.

Since there is no one-word process verb to express the idea of making something mandatory (we say *make/turn/render something mandatory*), there will be no one-word deverbal adjective (participle). As an option, I suggest:

```
ComponentTurnedMandatory
```

Comment: I’ve downvoted this answer because TurnedMandatoryComponent isn’t really English. Consider something like HotLicks’ suggestion, *mandated*, instead.

Comment: @Lawrence "mandated" does not express the transition from "optional" to "mandatory" requested by OP.

Comment: Since it is a state change, to say that something *is* mandated does express the transition from optional to non-optional.

Comment: ... *Mandated* is as expressive of a transition as the OP’s own *deleted* and *updated*.

Comment: @Lawrence I'm quite conflicted on this. If I think of `mandated` purely as an adjective, I'd say it wasn't expressive enough to imply a change of state -- it just says "this is a mandatory thing". However, if you treat it as a verb that's being used as an adjective, then you're right that `mandated` says "this thing has been mandated". For some reason `updated` and `deleted` seem clearer as "action" words, whereas "mandated" still has this level of ambiguity around it as "is it something that's happened, or is that just how it is?". Oh my head hurts...

Comment: Actually if you consider that both `mandatory` and `mandated` are adjectives, perhaps the former is for expressing "this thing is mandatory" and the latter is to express "this thing has become mandatory". [Definition 11](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/mandated?s=t) implies as much...

Comment: @LawrenceWagerfield I get where you’re coming from. Saying that something is mandated references its state. It’s the same with *deleted* and *updated*, but they have stronger links to the transition. Interestingly, though, even the dictionary you cite doesn’t list *mandate[d]* as an adjective. I suppose you could use the verb form *mandate* to express the transition.